# Define multiple setter methods in concern with custom names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to define multiple custom methods to set values for custom user fields in the UserConcern, that are not stored in the DB, but are fetched from outer source. I tried the code below, which results in ``': undefined local variable or method `get_custom_attrs' for UserConcern:Module (NameError)`

```
get_custom_attrs.each do |key|
  define_method(key) do
    // returning the value for this key
  end
end

private

def get_custom_attrs
  OuterConcern::FIELDS - User.attribute_names
end
```

I obviously can't use this method on the top level. If I switch to using a constant variable within the concern, such as `CUSTOM_FIELDS = [:custom1, custom2, ...]` that will work, but it's not dynamic and I'll have to change it every time a field is changed, added or deleted.

Comment: I don't see a `get_attrs` method defined here at all but you could just use `attr_accessor *get_custom_attr` which will create virtual attributes for the keys defined (since you said in the post you want to set the values and you code suggests retrieval.

Comment: It's a typo. Fixed it, it should be `get_custom_attrs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_custom_attrs` is being executed at the class level, whilst `def get_custom_attrs` defines the method at the instance level. You need `get_custom_attrs` to exist as a class method, so you want something like

```
class MyAwesomeClass
  class << self
    private
    def get_custom_attrs
      [:a1,:a2,:a3] # or whatever
    end
  end
  get_custom_attrs.each do |attr|
    # Some stuff happens here
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I preserve the original idea of making the `get_custom_attrs` method private?

Comment: What if I want to use that on the class level and instance level? I need to use that within another method and it won't work.

Comment: @abpetkov, usually for things like this I have something like `def the_method; self.class.the_method; end`, but the definition of a private method in Ruby is that it cannot be called with a receiver, so that'll throw an exception. In this case, either `get_custom_attrs` isn't actually a private method, or you're absolutely sure that it is but still want to work around that by using send, so you'd write something like `def the_method; self.class.send(:the_method); end`

Comment: @ymbirrt there's something else though, the OuterConcern:: FIELDS that contains an array of symbols will not work for some reason. Hardcoding the array as you mentioned will work, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: @abpetkov, `[:a1, :a2, :a3]`  can be replaced with any arbitrary code, the snipped in my answer is just an example. Note that it'll be executed when the class is defined and never again afterwards. As for `OuterConcern::FIELDS` not working for some reason, I'm afraid I can't investigate that, and it sounds like a separate question.